# Are Python classes in Spark notebooks beneficial or common in the data scientist community?

Tags: python

Being a software developer, I am coming from an object-oriented programming background, and I think in terms of classes and objects.

I am currently working on a `Spark` notebook to perform calculations on a dataset, for which I am following a more procedural approach (i.e. adding new columns to a `dataframe` as I perform the calculations.)

My question is if it is common among data scientists to use classes in their `Spark` notebooks to encapsulate functionality as opposed to following a more procedural approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you are writing pipelines and you relay on fact that "you run n+1 cell only if previous n completed with success" and you don't have to rely on super structurized code. On the other hand you want to have some functionalities closed in classes/functions and then run them with different parameters, but don't stick too much to classes since 90% of work is prototyping. After all if you written your code in propper way making it as class shouldn't be much of a hassle, so code should be clean and clear but structurizing it makes iterations very slow.

So rule of a thumb you close code into class only when you want to reuse it and you are sure it will remain like this for very long time

Comment: Thanks very much for those guidelines.